# scala - Higher kinded type in trait member: _$1 takes no type parameters, expected: 1

Tags: scala, higher-kinded-types, type-constructor

I think there is something I don't quite well understand when I have the following code:

```
trait Configuration[F[_]] {
  def get(key: String): F[ConfigValue]
}

class InMemoryConfig extends Configuration[Option] {
  override def get(key: String): Option[ConfigValue] = ???
}

class InFileConfig(path: String) extends Configuration[Try] {
  override def get(key: String): Try[ConfigValue] = ???
}

trait Logging {
  def config: Configuration[_] // does not work
  // ...
}

class DefaultLogging {
  override val config = new InMemoryConfig
  // ...
}
```

The name of the classes are pretty much meaningless, the *general* goal is to have a member in the trait without defining the param type in order to *delay* the choice until the implementation (actually in the `DefaultLogging` class).

Comment: That **worked** @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez (I guess I already tried something alike) but then, if I _inject_ `Logging` in another trait(s) I am _dragging_ the _e**F**fect_, right? I mean, I have to do `trait Another[F[_]] { def logger: Logging[F] ... }` and so on?

Comment: Yeah, which makes sense. However, a better question is if you need that chain of dependencies but that is more an opinion-based question and probably one that would be better to discuss in a chat space like the multiple **discord** servers.

Comment: Agreed! Thanks for your help! (if you raise the first comment to a question I can accept)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `Logging` doesn't know which type constructor will be used for the `Configuration` it has to carry over it like any other type parameter.

Thus:

```scala
trait Logging[F[_]] {
  def config: Configuration[F]
  // ...
}
```

---

The same will apply to whatever depends on `Logging` it needs to specify the type or keep the dependency.
Thus, a common observation would be if such direct dependency is needed or not, but that becomes a matter of design and sometimes personal preference.